# WiFi adapter Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 not found after updating to 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

After updating to 18.04, but Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless adapter is not found.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac 
 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30).
 Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035]. 
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci.
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci.
```

Comment: What is the problem? What does your internal QCA9377 have to do with tethering?

Comment: Sorry but I have clubbed 2 questions. Network controller was mentioned for WiFi problem. In settings it says "No Wi-Fi adapter found". Usb tethering worked twice thrice after the update and now it doesn't. For that I tried solutions mentioned on askubuntu, but found no luck.

Comment: I suggest that you edit this question to ask about 'no wifi adapter found' and then start a new question about tethering. Please include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30).                
 Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035].         
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci.       
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci.

Comment: @guntbert please specify what information do you want. I am a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: @AkshayAbhyankar Sorry, I didn't explain. Take the text from your comment and move it into the question. A question should contain everything necessary to answer it. Comments may get lost eventually.